# Redirect from secure https to http for only one page

Tags: php, http, redirect, https, apache2

I have a page, `page.php` that I need to be redirected to `http` if it is accessed through `https` because otherwise my google ads won't show up.

To be precise, I would like the following to happen:

`https://site.com/page.php?blah=foo?bar=blah` --> `http://site.com/page.php?blah=foo?bar=blah`

I have so far tried :

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} on`

`RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might also be a quick copy paste

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
    $url = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Awwh, yeah, PHP redirects so much better than unintelligible apache rewrite nonsense which works "sometimes." Also, use isset to check if $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is even set. Don't want to get php warnings on pages that are not request as HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443')
{
   header('location:http://url.com');
}
```

if the secure port is set to other than 443 this will not work so 
you can also use

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'
```

Comment: do you mean `//change to http` ? And would I do a meta refresh to accomplish this? 

I was more after a .htaccess method though if you know of one?

Comment: this was tagged PHP, you should just tag it htaccess if you don't want PHP.  the first answer is working perfectly for me right now.